# Regarding first order differential operator and derivative endomorphism

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebroids

I am reading "[Differential operators and actions of Lie algebroids](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0209337)" by Kosmann-Schwarzbach and Mackenzie.

There is some confusion regarding the terminology.

Let $E\rightarrow M$ be a vector bundle.

A first order differential operator on $\Gamma(M,E)$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $D:\Gamma(M,E)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E)$ for which there exists **a vector field $D_M$ of $M$** such that $D(f\alpha)=fD(\alpha)+D_M(f)\alpha$ for all $f\in C^\infty(M)$ and $\alpha\in \Gamma(M,E)$.

A derivative endomorphism of $\Gamma(M,E)$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $D:\Gamma(M,E)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E)$ for which there exists **an $\mathbb{R}$-linear endomorphism $D_M$ of $C^\infty(M)$** such that $D(f\alpha)=fD(\alpha)+D_M(f)\alpha$ for all $f\in C^\infty(M)$ and $\alpha\in \Gamma(M,E)$.

There is some inconsistency with the terminology used in "[General theory of Lie groupoids and Lie algebroids](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781107325883)" but that is not my question here.

The paper says that if we start with a derivative endomorphism, then "it follows that $D$ is a first order differential operator." I do not understand how is this straightforward or if it is correct at all.

If I take any first order differential operator $D$, then, ignoring that $D_M$ (which is a vector field) has a derivation property, we can just focus on the $\mathbb{R}$-linearity and conclude that $D$ is a derivative endomorphism of $\Gamma(M,E)$. So, any first order differential operator should be a derivative endomorphism. But, the same paper says "a first-order differential operator is a derivative endomorphism of $\Gamma(M,E)$ if and only if it has scalar symbol."

What is that I am misunderstanding here?

The terminology is interchanged in the Mackenzie's book "[General theory of Lie groupoids and Lie algebroids](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781107325883)". What is called here as first order differential operator is called as derivative endomorphism there and vice versa.

I also think the name "derivative endomorphism" should be used when $D_M$ is a vector field, a derivation of $C^\infty(M)$.

Comment: As mentioned by Dmitri Pavlov, what I mentioned above is not the definition of first order differential operators. I misquoted the lines from that paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting $f=f_1f_2$ in the definition of a derivative endomorphism immediately implies that $D_M$ is a derivation, using the fact that $g_1ψ=g_2ψ$ for all vector fields $ψ$ implies $g_1=g_2$, where $g_1$ and $g_2$ are smooth functions.

Thus, the two notions coincide.  An important remark: the first property in the original post does not define first-order differential operators, but rather singles out a special class of first-order differential operators that the authors want to study.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake in what I wrote as first order differential operator. I misquoted lines from that paper.

Comment: I am thinking of possible justification of using two names for same idea :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: They are not quite the same, as we have just seen: first-order differential operators form a strictly bigger class than derivative endomorphisms.